# How I create Google data studio Radar chart with more than 6 metrics value?

Tags: looker-studio, radar-chart

In google data studio, radar chart has metrics value maximum 6. But i want to display 9 value. Can any one help me who to show this ?

Answer (score 0):

The [Partner Visualization](https://datastudio.google.com/c/reporting/35be8ea6-3480-46bd-bc3d-ff2584c703ff?s=oHjeM82mH5I) from Clickinsight supports max 6 metrics. If you want to display additional metrics, you can either [build your own Community Visualization](https://developers.google.com/datastudio/visualization) or contact the partner with the feature request.